# Upload Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, web

This is my code, my photo can't be inserted into the database. I don't know where the problem is.

actually i want to make an online exam with the codeigniter. i want to upload the question with the pic. but when i tried to upload the pict, the code is not working.

but the question success inserted into the database. only the pict failed to upload

Controller :

```html
function insert(){
 $nama_asli = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
 $config ['file_name'] = $nama_asli;
 $config ['upload_path'] = './images/';
 $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
 $config ['max_size'] = '2500';
 $config ['max_width']  = '2600';
 $config ['max_height']  = '2200';
  
 
 $id_soal = '';
 $soal = $_POST['soal'];
 $a = $_POST['a'];
 $b = $_POST['b'];
 $c = $_POST['c'];
 $d = $_POST['d'];
 $kunci = $_POST['kunci'];
 $status = $_POST['status'];

 
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
   $error       = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
   $this->load->view('admin/home/create_admin', $error);
 }
 
 else{
 $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
 $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
 $file_name = $upload_data['file_name']; 
 $data = array(
  'id_soal' => $id_soal,
  'soal' => $soal,
  'a' => $a,
  'b' => $b,
  'c' => $c,
  'd' => $d,
  'kunci' => $kunci,
  'status' => $status,
  'foto' => $file_name,
  );
 $hasil = $this->soal_model->Simpan('soal', $data);
 if($hasil>=1){
  redirect('dashboard/index', $data);
 }
 }
 
}
```

Model :

```html
class Soal_model extends Ci_Model {

  public function Ambil($where= "") {
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from soal '.$where);
    return $data;
  }
  
  public function Simpan($tabel, $data){
    $res = $this->db->insert($tabel, $data);
    return $res;
  }
```

View:

```html
<form role="form" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/insert" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" style = "margin : 10px;">
  <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Soal :</label>
  <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="soal" id="soal" required></textarea>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban A :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="a" id="a" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban B :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="b" id="b" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban C :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="c" id="c" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Jawaban D :</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Type Here" name="d" id="d" required/>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Kunci :</label>
  <select name="kunci" id="kunci" class="form-control">
  <option>Select</option> 
  <option>A</option>  
  <option>B</option> 
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  </select> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Status :</label>
  <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select</option> 
  <option value="tampil">Tampil</option>  
  <option value="tidak">Tidak</option> 
  </select> 
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
  <label>Photo :</label>
  <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" size="20"/>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <div class="form-group"> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Simpan</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Hapus</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Database :

[image]

Anyone can help?

Comment: it looks ok, try changing this `$config ['upload_path'] = './images';` to `$config ['upload_path'] = './images/';`

Comment: there is no result. same like before. the picture haven't uploaded

Comment: Are you using 2 forms? There is Form inside form in your view file

Comment: my mistake... but now i've already fixed that form

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the do_upload method of upload::library

```
$nama_asli                = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$config ['file_name']     = $nama_asli;
$config ['upload_path']   = './images/';
$config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config ['max_size']      = '2500';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//you need to add this do_upload();
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $error       = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
}
else{
    $data        = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $file_name   = $this->upload->file_name;
    .
    .
    .
    ...
}
```

Comment: i've already updated my controller. please check my new updated. thanks before

Comment: now, did you have some error or the problem is solved?

Comment: actually the problem is not solved. do you think there is wrong pattern in my new controller?

Comment: quit `$config ['file_name']     = $nama_asli;`

Comment: there is no diffrent

Comment: some times i have find a bug using `jpeg`, quit it, and what is the real path of your image folder `/var/www/project/images/` ?

Comment: my project folder name is newton. inside that folder i made folder named images for the upload path. so i used code ./images/